# Get page feed from Facebook public page Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

Iam trying to fetch the list of Page feed from a Public page from Facebook into my Android app.

I have the Page Id and the access_token for the page. Iam trying to fetch the feed with a request using the following url:-

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed?access_token=sometoken"
```

But doing the above gives me the following error:-

```
Tried accessing non existent field (feed) on node type (Open Graph Object)
```

I tried it from Google chrome's Postman extension as well. Gives me the same error.

How can I solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JustAnotherDotNetDev I have ut in "sometoken" in the the question for security reasons. I have it there originally in the url

Comment: @JustAnotherDotNetDev You should NEVER post any access tokens in the public!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the page-id is a numeric value, chances might be that you are getting the wrong value.

You might want to try using either of the below solutions :-

1) Use page username instead of the numeric page-id.

2) Replacing feed with posts.

Something like so:-

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/page-username/posts?access_token=sometoken"
```

Comment: @helloworld, How are you getting the access_token? Nothing I do seems to work.

Comment: @craned Simply create an url to fetch the access token like so :-  string accessTokenUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + <App Id>) + "&client_secret=" + <Client Secret key> + "&grant_type=client_credentials";
            var access_token = await FetchPageDetails(accessTokenUrl);

You can find FetchPageDetails() here http://pastebin.com/xRVkQqQG

Comment: `sometoken` should probably be wrapped in a `URLEncoder.encodeUTF8(sometoken)` or the pipe that is part of the `access_token` won't be allowed.

Comment: from where i can find the access token

Answer (score 0):

To me, the error message hints that the `page_id` you're using is not a real `page_id`. You're replacing it with a real numeric id in the request, right? If the `object_id` is a page, the request should work.

You can check the type of the `object_id` with

```
/{object_id}?metadata=1&fields=id,name,metadata{type}
```

For example, for the CocaCola page

```
/40796308305?metadata=1&fields=id,name,metadata{type}
```

it returns

```
{
  "id": "40796308305",
  "name": "Coca-Cola",
  "metadata": {
    "type": "page"
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly; the fact that the error message says `on node type (Open Graph Object)` indicates that the id is not of a Facebook page, but of an external URL.